# turn my phonegap cordova gps tracking system to work on boot or as a service

Tags: android, cordova, gps, phonegap-plugins, tracking

I have an android phonegap cordova gps tracking system who sends location to remote server database depending on the database (Name, user & password) on php file on the cordova App.

- the server side written by php and its Ok.
- my problem is if i go back on App it stops sending location because it not working in background.

my question is:

How to turn my App to work on boot or as a service in background in a simple way
step by step please i'm not professional :-)

Comment: You have to write native code, this does not work using cordova. Before you start thinking about it, read the store guides, not everything what can be done, is allowed in a public app.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, you mean it can't be done and i have to start over @Joerg

Answer (score 0):

**Background Cordova GeoLocation:**

What you need to do first is, you need to add a [backgroudgeolocation plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation), which helps you to do the kind of service you need to add with your application.

**Using the plugin**

The plugin creates the object window.plugins.backgroundGeoLocation with the methods

```
configure(success, fail, option),

start(success, fail)

stop(success, fail).
```

**Installing the plugin:**

cordova plugin add https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation.git
ACHTUNG! If you're not using Cordova 5.x, you must use the tagged branch #cordova-4.x to install the plugin, like this (Because Cordova has migrated to npm)

cordova plugin add https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation.git#cordova-4.x
A full example could be:

```
//
//
// after deviceready
//
//

// Your app must execute AT LEAST ONE call for the current position via standard Cordova geolocation,
//  in order to prompt the user for Location permission.
window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location) {
    console.log('Location from Phonegap');
});

var bgGeo = window.plugins.backgroundGeoLocation;

/**
* This would be your own callback for Ajax-requests after POSTing background geolocation to your server.
*/
var yourAjaxCallback = function(response) {
    ////
    // IMPORTANT:  You must execute the #finish method here to inform the native plugin that you're finished,
    //  and the background-task may be completed.  You must do this regardless if your HTTP request is successful or not.
    // IF YOU DON'T, ios will CRASH YOUR APP for spending too much time in the background.
    //
    //
    bgGeo.finish();
};

/**
* This callback will be executed every time a geolocation is recorded in the background.
*/
var callbackFn = function(location) {
    console.log('[js] BackgroundGeoLocation callback:  ' + location.latitude + ',' + location.longitude);
    // Do your HTTP request here to POST location to your server.
    //
    //
    yourAjaxCallback.call(this);
};

var failureFn = function(error) {
    console.log('BackgroundGeoLocation error');
}

// BackgroundGeoLocation is highly configurable.
bgGeo.configure(callbackFn, failureFn, {
    url: 'http://only.for.android.com/update_location.json', // <-- Android ONLY:  your server url to send locations to
    params: {
        auth_token: 'user_secret_auth_token',    //  <-- Android ONLY:  HTTP POST params sent to your server when persisting locations.
        foo: 'bar'                              //  <-- Android ONLY:  HTTP POST params sent to your server when persisting locations.
    },
    headers: {                                   // <-- Android ONLY:  Optional HTTP headers sent to your configured #url when persisting locations
        "X-Foo": "BAR"
    },
    desiredAccuracy: 10,
    stationaryRadius: 20,
    distanceFilter: 30,
    notificationTitle: 'Background tracking', // <-- android only, customize the title of the notification
    notificationText: 'ENABLED', // <-- android only, customize the text of the notification
    activityType: 'AutomotiveNavigation',
    debug: true, // <-- enable this hear sounds for background-geolocation life-cycle.
    stopOnTerminate: false // <-- enable this to clear background location settings when the app terminates
});

// Turn ON the background-geolocation system.  The user will be tracked whenever they suspend the app.
bgGeo.start();

// If you wish to turn OFF background-tracking, call the #stop method.
// bgGeo.stop()
```

NOTE: The plugin includes org.apache.cordova.geolocation as a dependency. You must enable Cordova's GeoLocation in the foreground and have the user accept Location services by executing #watchPosition or #getCurrentPosition.

First, copy the SampleApp out of the repo and into any folder you wish (eg: tmp).

```
$ cp -R cordova-plugin-background-geolocation/example/SampleApp ./tmp
$ cd tmp/SampleApp
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation.git
$ cordova platform add ios
$ cordova build ios
```

For more information click on the below link:

[**Cordova background-geolocation**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation)

Cheers, Happy coding.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, i'm stuck.. can you help me to find a paid service to done that ? @Nemo

Comment: Check the link in the end of the answer. You will find the solution

Comment: Hi, thanks you very much Mr. Nemo , i meant a paid service to modify my app not to buy new app, It is difficult for me to change it, if you can help me with that please send me your email i will contact you 
Thanks @Nemo